# Pyramid mongodb scaffold failing on Python 3 due to Paste

Tags: pyramid

Environment:

- Python 3.2.3 (using virtualenv)
- Pyramid 1.4
- pyramid_mongodb scaffold

After installing myproject using pyramid_mongodb scaffold I ran `python setup.py test -q` and it's failing with below errors.

```
running build_ext
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 33, in <module>
    """,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/distutils/dist.py", line 917, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/distutils/dist.py", line 936, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/root/App/Big3/lib/python3.2/site-packages/distribute-0.6.24-py3.2.egg/setuptools    /command/test.py", line 137, in run
    self.with_project_on_sys_path(self.run_tests)
  File "/root/App/Big3/lib/python3.2/site-packages/distribute-0.6.24-py3.2.egg/setuptools    /command/test.py", line 117, in with_project_on_sys_path
    func()
  File "/root/App/Big3/lib/python3.2/site-packages/distribute-0.6.24-py3.2.egg/setuptools    /command/test.py", line 146, in run_tests
    testLoader = loader_class()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/unittest/main.py", line 123, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/unittest/main.py", line 191, in parseArgs
    self.createTests()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/unittest/main.py", line 198, in createTests
    self.module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/unittest/loader.py", line 132, in loadTestsFromNames
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/unittest/loader.py", line 132, in <listcomp>
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/unittest/loader.py", line 91, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__('.'.join(parts_copy))
  File "/root/App/Big3/Lime/lime/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pyramid.config import Configurator
  File "/root/App/Big3/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pyramid-1.4.1-py3.2.egg/pyramid/config    /__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from webob.exc import WSGIHTTPException as WebobWSGIHTTPException
  File "/root/App/Big3/lib/python3.2/site-packages/WebOb-1.2.3-py3.2.egg/webob/exc.py",         line 1115, in <module>
    from paste import httpexceptions
  File "/root/App/Big3/lib/python3.2/site-packages/Paste-1.7.5.1-py3.2.egg/paste                /httpexceptions.py", line 634
        except HTTPException, exc:
                        ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I understand the error, that Paste is not python3 compatible. I also know how to fix it but that would essentially mean porting Paste to python3 (which is something I don't want to do), so can anyone tell what I can do?

From the error stack I see that `webob/exc.py` is doing `from paste import httpexceptions`  but when I checked the code I see that the import is under a `try` `except` block (without raising any error in `except`), so I even tried the test after removing `paste` from the `lib` but then when I run the test, I see that the setup.py is installing `paste` again

```
running test
Checking .pth file support in .
/root/App/Big3/bin/python -E -c pass
Searching for Paste>=1.7.1
```

I checked .pth files and removed reference to `paste` and then started re-installation of project but somehow it still sees `paste` as required

```
Installed /root/App/Big3/Myproject
Processing dependencies for Myproject==0.0
Searching for Paste>=1.7.1
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/Paste/
```

My setup.py file is same as [this](https://github.com/niallo/pyramid_mongodb/blob/master/setup.py)
Can someone tell me where is this `paste` dependency coming into my project.

Comment: Well obviously pyramid_mongodb does not support Python 3. Your best bet is to look at the scaffold and use parts of it to serve your purposes without getting bogged down in the intimate details of something that generates code that you're supposed to modify anyway.

Comment: I suppose my frustration is that I compared pyramid_mongosbd scaffold side by side with the other working ones and ensured that they look alike (with only the necessary changes for supporting mongodb) but still paste is getting imported (and thus getting executed) and I am not able to get why it's happening. But still thanks for looking into this and commenting.

Comment: After a little more investigation I think it's the WebError import which is inturn calling paste and that's why failing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I didn't intend to answer my own question but since I have made changes which are working for me, I thought I will share it here (assuming that there would be other folks wanting to have pyramid_mongodb scaffold work on python3)

**Changes in development. ini**

Removed

```
[pipeline:main]
pipeline =
    egg:WebError#evalerror
    {{project}}
```

Changed

```
[app:{{project}}] to [app:main]
```

Added (optional)

```
pyramid.includes =
    pyramid_debugtoolbar
```

Changed server (from paste to waitress)

```
[server:main]
use = egg:waitress#main
host = 0.0.0.0
port = 6543
```

**Changes in Setup.py**
changed requires from

```
requires = ['pyramid', 'WebError', 'pymongo']
```

to

```
requires = ['pyramid', 'pyramid_debugtoolbar', 'pymongo', 'uwsgi', 'waitress']
```

It's important to remove webError

The application is now working...

Comment: Good catch. You should accept your answer. I'll also point out that weberror is very much unmaintained any longer and will not be ported to Python 3. You can alternatively use various combinations of the debugtoolbar and pyramid_exclog or roll your own alternative.

Comment: Thanx for answer. Everything was ok except uwsgi package, so I needed to delete it from requires list.