# Attempting to deploy a python pyramid application with uWSGI

Tags: python, pyramid, uwsgi

I'm attempting to deploy a pyramid application using uWSGI.

The application works fine when served with the included pyramid development server.

Also, I have set this up before, and I swear it worked at one time.

However, putting in the magic phrases right now is resulting in "This webpage is not available"

I'm trying to keep all of the configuration parameters as similar as possible to what I have currently so I don't have to worry about firewall issues.

uWSGI section in development.ini looks like this (from: [Setup uWSGI as webserver with pyramid (no NGINX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351559/setup-uwsgi-as-webserver-with-pyramid-no-nginx)):

```
[uwsgi]
socket = localhost:8080
virtualenv = /var/www/finance/finance-env
die-on-term = 1
master = 1
#logto = /var/log/wsgi/uwsgi.log


enable-threads = true
offload-threads = N
py-autoreload = 1
wsgi-file = /var/www/finance/wsgi.py
```

wsgy.py looks like this:

```
from pyramid.paster import get_app, setup_logging
ini_path = '/var/www/finance/corefinance/development.ini'
setup_logging(ini_path)
application = get_app(ini_path, 'main')
```

Here's the output right now. Everything seems to be listening just fine on port 8080.

```
user1@finance1:~$ sudo /var/www/finance/finance-env/bin/uwsgi --ini-paste-logg /var/www/finance/corefinance/development.ini
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /var/www/finance/corefinance/development.ini
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.11.2 (64bit) on [Fri Jan 15 21:13:31 2016] ***
compiled with version: 4.7.2 on 16 November 2015 20:13:35
os: Linux-4.1.5-x86_64-linode61 #7 SMP Mon Aug 24 13:46:31 EDT 2015
nodename: finance1
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /home/user1
detected binary path: /var/www/finance/finance-env/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) ***
your processes number limit is 3934
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address localhost:8080 fd 3
Python version: 3.2.3 (default, Feb 20 2013, 14:49:46)  [GCC 4.7.2]
Set PythonHome to /var/www/finance/finance-env
Python main interpreter initialized at 0xfd0a10
python threads support enabled
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 145536 bytes (142 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 1 seconds on interpreter 0xfd0a10 pid: 6275 (default app)
mountpoint  already configured. skip.
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 6275)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 6282, cores: 1)
Python auto-reloader enabled
```

Comment: `http = 0.0.0.0:8080`     instead of `socket = localhost:8080` in the ini file

Comment: `http` uses uwsgi's http routing, without it you need to be behind a proxy like nginx

Comment: @reptilicus That did it.  Want to answer for credit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are behind a proxy such as nginx, you need to use the internal http routing support in uwsgi, change

```
socket = localhost:8080
```

to

```
http = 0.0.0.0:8080
```

Here are the [uwsgi http support docs](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/HTTP.html)